# Postgres initdb does nothing on Windows 2019?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm using Ansible to install Postgres 13 on a Windows 2019 machine. I downloaded the binaries from [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries) and unzipped it to `C:\PostgreSQL\13\pgsql`, and added the path to the system path, all via Ansible tasks. I then have an Ansible task that does

```
initdb -D I:\PostgreSQL\13\DATA -U postgres -E UTF8
```

and it fails, with the only error being a non-zero return code

So to test, I launch Windows Powershell and enter `initdb -V`, I get nothing - no error, no feedback, NOTHING! Adding the `-d` (debug) option does nothing.

I've even downloaded the zip file manually and re-unzipped to no avail. What the hell is going on?